# blocked FFT of signal with frequency noise

Tags: python, fft

I have a signal with a phase that is around 40 Hz, with small amounts of noise. I am trying to analyze it to find the frequency in 1 second blocks, I am using python to do a simulation of this. I found that the blocked FFT analysis was not accurate, so I looked at specific blocks to see why this was happening and found that at later times, the FFT was not making sense and having a spike around the 40 Hz where it should. I am using Python for this simulation and here is the code:

First create the signal:

```
# Time
time = 500
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 5000.0
sample_freq = 1.0/T
#number of points
N = time / T
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
noise = np.random.normal(scale = 0.01, size = len(x))
noisy_freq = 40 + noise
y = 50.0 * np.sin(noisy_freq * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 1.0*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
```

Then I looked at the FFT for the first second and receive:

[image: first second]

and zoomed in to around 40 Hz

[image: zoom of first second]

Then I looked at the 10th second block:

[image: 10th second]

and zoomed to around 40 Hz:

[image: 10th second zoom]

It is visible the signal is degrading already and this horizontal line is beginning to develop which I'm not sure what is is from.

Then I looked at the 100th second and this is what I found:

[image: 100th second]

and zoomed to around 40 Hz:

[image: 100th second zoom]

and the FFT response is showing barely any certainty of a spike around 40 Hz. I cannot figure out why the signal degrades at later times. I have tried using windowing functions, but this does not help.

Here is the code I use to create the FFT:

```
sample_freq = 1/T
time_step = 10
step = int(time_step * sample_freq)

x = x[100/T:101/T]
y = y[100/T:101/T]

flat = flat_top_windowing(len(y))
y = y*flat

yf = np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))
x_n = x.size

xf = np.fft.fftfreq(x_n,1/sample_freq)

plt.close()
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * yf[0:N/2])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the generated signal:

```
np.sin(noisy_freq * 2.0*np.pi*x)
```

As the time advances (values in variable `x`), the multiplication `noisy_freq*x` means that `noisy_freq` variations have an ever increasing impact on the `sin` phase. Given increasing phase variations, the actual instantaneous frequency varies that much more (to the extent that it eventually looks like it randomly jumps all over the whole spectrum).

To generate a frequency modulated signal, you should instead integrate the frequency contributions with:

```
dphi = 2.0*np.pi*noisy_freq[:-1]*T; # per sample frequency contributions
dphi = np.insert(dphi, 0, 0);       # set the initial phase to 0
phi  = np.cumsum(dphi);             # integrate phase

y = 50.0 * np.sin(phi) + 1.0*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
```

Comment: I think this makes sense. So, lets say at time 1, the random noise added on the 40 Hz is .1 Hz, so it will be sin((40 + 0.1) * 2 *pi * 1) = sin(80*pi + .2*pi) which is a small amount of frequency noise. Then later at say time 100 it would be sin((40 + 0.1) * 2 * pi * 100) = sin(800*pi + 20*pi) which is a lot bigger frequency noise. So the noise is actually increasing with the time, which is only an artifact of the way I created the signal, right?